# Google cloud functions http authentication

Tags: google-cloud-functions, http-authentication

I am new to google cloud functions and try to restrict access to my function by only requests from dialogflow webhooks. I see two options in gcloud console: allow unauthenticated requests and restrict by user accounts. I don't understand how to implement that authentication. Dialogflow webhooks has options to set http headers that sets in webhook requests. But gcloud console hasn't interface/options to obtain any data that I can write as http authentication header. So I see only option implement authetication flow in cloud function, but in that way why google added option to restrict access by http authentication. Can anyone give me an example step-by-step example how to obtain http headers names and data needed to implement http authentication on cloud functions from dialogflow webhooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't built in authentication, you have to perform it by yourselves. You have some guidance [here in the Google Cloud Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/fulfillment-webhook#auth)

In summary, set your function public (allow unauthenticated) and perform the check in your code.