# Google Identity Platform authentication inside Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-identity

Although similar to [Google cloud functions http authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61017762/google-cloud-functions-http-authentication), my question is more specific towards Google Identity Platform (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform).

I am new to GCP. I have created a username/password provider in Identity Platform. I created a sample flask app client and used FireBaseUI to perform basic user login. I am able to get the accessToken in the client.

Then I created a Cloud Function (select unauthenticated as per the above thread). Then passed the accessToken in "Authorization: Bearer" header. I am able to access the token inside the Cloud Function.

But the next part I am unable to figure out is how do I validate that token against Identity Platform and get the user details?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to protect firebase Cloud Function HTTP endpoint using authenticated id token and database rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575730/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-using-authenticated-id-toke)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To verify a token, you will want to retrieve the value of the passed in "Authorization" HTTP header.  This will be a string that starts with "Bearer ".  The remainder is a JWT token that can be passed to verifyIdToken() and you will be returned a decoded token that has been verified.  From that data you will be able to use the properties within (eg. "email").

See:

[Verify ID tokens using the Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#verify_id_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk)

---

```
from flask import abort
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import auth

default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

def test_firebase_auth(request):
    authorization = request.headers.get('Authorization')
    id_token = None
    if authorization and authorization.startswith('Bearer '):
        id_token = authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]
    else:
        abort(401)

    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
        return str(decoded_token)
        uid = decoded_token['uid']
        # log.info(decoded_token)
        return uid
    except Exception as e: # ValueError or auth.AuthError
        return str(e)
        abort(401)
```

Comment: Hi @Kolban Sorry forgot to mention it, I have been through that link, but somehow I am finding GCP documentation very hard to to follow. (AWS was very straight forward).
How do I add the firebase admin sdk to the Cloud Function? Where do I get the auth variable from? `decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)`

Comment: This might be a good reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48575730/how-to-protect-firebase-cloud-function-http-endpoint-using-authenticated-id-toke

Comment: thank you for the pointers. I was able to come up with a Python solution. I updated your answer with the solution and marked it accepted as a thank you.

Comment: This too helped https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-cloud-functions/secure-cloud-functions-with-firebase-authentication/